# How to install Ruby on a Linode server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, linode

As the title says, what's the best way to install Ruby and then Ruby on Rails on a Linode server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). Everything is well documented and it comes with an installer.

Answer (score 1):

Linode have plenty of documentation in the Library section of their website: http://library.linode.com/search?query=Ruby

Answer (score 1):

I can't address Linode specifically. But they provide shell access it seems and if you've got that you're home free.

Personally I'd install [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ryan Bate's screen casts.  He has one (not free but cheap at $9/mo) for deploying a rails app to Linode (or any VPS for that matter).

Even though you might not be developing in Rails, he covers basic setup of an Ubuntu machine.

Very informative.

http://railscasts.com/